# Refresh dynamic module on change in nestjs

Tags: nestjs, nodemailer

app.module.ts

```
import { MailerModule, MailerOptions } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        MailerModule.forRootAsync({
            imports: [ServiceModule],
            inject: [ConfigService],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
                return  await configService.getMailserver(true);
            }
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
})
```

The config for the MailerModule is read from the database. This also works for the bootstrap of the app. Only if the app is started and then I make changes in the database, how can I reload the module without a complete nestjs restart? currently the configuration loaded at bootstrap remains until the restart.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this one @pasek?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the nestjs application must be restarted manually..

Answer (score 0):

**The good news:**
there is a built-in solution in `nest.js` called `useFeature` that does exactly that from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#community-guidelines):

> **register**, you are expecting to configure a dynamic module with a specific configuration for use only by the calling module. For example, with Nest's @nestjs/axios: HttpModule.register({ baseUrl: 'someUrl' }). If, in another module you use HttpModule.register({ baseUrl: 'somewhere else' }), it will have the different configuration. You can do this for as many modules as you want.

> **forRoot**, you are expecting to configure a dynamic module once and reuse that configuration in multiple places (though possibly unknowingly as it's abstracted away). This is why you have one GraphQLModule.forRoot(), one TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), etc.

> **forFeature**, you are expecting to use the configuration of a dynamic module's forRoot but need to modify some configuration specific to the calling module's needs (i.e. which repository this module should have access to, or the context that a logger should use.)

**The bad news:** not enough code examples or a detailed documentation about this feature and how to use it. And this is not the first time someone stumbles for the exact same issue. Just take a look at this [thread](https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/issues/7#issuecomment-591771792):

> You can use .forFeatureAsync() to provide your models, as outlined in the documentation, and inject the other modules into the factory functions you define in the exact same way you would in a service. The only difference being that you do not decorate any schema factory method parameters with@InjectModel, but instead add an entry in the inject array of the forFeatureAsync where the entry is defined by using the getModelToken() method from mongoose.util.ts mentioned in the testing portion of the documentation.

**What you should do:**

First, check if your mailer module supports the `forFeatureAsync` (spoiler alert - [it doesn't](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/blob/master/lib/mailer.module.ts)).

Second, dig in and get the [service definition](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/blob/master/lib/mailer.service.ts) of the mailer, So `MailerService` is available and you can initiate it however you like. Now you can manage your memory to suit configuration updates to your `mailer instance` or maybe even develop your own module with proper `forFeature` and `forFeatureAsyncAsync` methods.

Hope you will find the way that suits you most... good luck